# How to compare the differences of two folders and save in new folder

Tags: file-management

I want to compare the differences between two folders and then copy the differences to a NEW folder.

I have seen existing software like winmerge and robo copy that allows you to copy the differences between two folders and synchronise the two folders so that the contents of each folder are the same. However, I do not want to do this.

I want the differences of the two folders to be saved within a different folder/location. Also - happy to take on recommendations for scripts rather than software i.e. cmd, python etc.

Comment: https://lifehacker.com/compare-the-contents-of-two-folders-with-the-diff-comma-598872057

Comment: did you try the solution that I have proposed in the answer?

Answer (score 3):

**Use diff command:**

Let's say you have two folder:

- `folder-1`
- `folder-2`

In this case, the command should be:

```
diff -rq folder-1 folder-2 > /tmp/mydiff.diff
```

The results are saved in your new file `mydiff.diff` within the folder `/tmp`. Use the folder that fits with your need.

You must run the command from within the `masterFolder` that contains the two subfolder:

```
masterFolder
├── folder-1
├── folder-2
```

Example:

```
user@user-pc:~/Document/masterFolder/ $ diff -rq folder-1 folder-2 > /tmp/mydiff.diff
```

Remember to substitute `folder-1` and `folder-2` with the name of your folder!!

Comment: I am prompted with the response "The system cannot find the path specified". 
Lets say the two folders are called 'rushhour' and 'ran'. I want the files within the two folders to be compared. Any differences I want to be saved in a new folder. This new folder should contain all the files that were not present in both folders. Thanks v.much for your prompt response btw, much appreciated!

Comment: in ordet to run the command, you must be inside the folder that contein the two. I am going to update the answer

Comment: Thanks v.much for updating your response so promptly. I am afraid that the workaround you provided doesn't work and I am still prompted with an error "The system cannot find the path specified". I have navigated to the master folder and updated the file names respectively. I want to confirm that this is to be done within CMD prompt?